# how to get the subscription level for permissions in my android app

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-developer-api

I want to understand how I can have protection level: Android signature for my application. Should I only take my app to the playstore? More and more permissions have this type of restrictions over time and I wanted to know if it would be possible and if so how to have this level of access. Below is the link and photo of an example of permission that requires this level of access.

[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#WRITE_SETTING](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#WRITE_SETTINGS)

I tried searching the documentation, YouTube, and the like. But nothing has given me a solution yet.